# Passing paramters from one JSP to an other for a servlet, the information is not being passed

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a simple problem but I just can't get the darn thing to work. Here is the code I am using. When I click on the button in main.jsp, I get an updated image, from reportbuilder.do, but it's a blank image (actually, it gives a time stamp in the image to show a new image has been created). In reportbuilder.do I can see the reportType, reportScope, and reportTime are all null. What am I doing wrong?

main.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Failing example</title>
        <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#updateReport").click(function() {
                    $("#chart1").load("/chart.jsp?reportType=${reportType}&reportScope=${reportScope}&reportTime=${reportTime}");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <div id="chart1">
        <img src="/reportbuilder.do?">
    </div>
    <div id="dropDown1">
        <form method="GET" action="/chart.jsp">
            <select name="reportType" style="width:100%">
                <option value="devBugFix">Developer Bug Fixes</option>
                <option value="devHrsWork">Developer Hours Worked</option>
            </select>
            <select name="reportScope" style="width:100%">
                <option value="cmcProg">CMC Program</option>
                <option value="equFarmAs">Equestrian Farmer's Association</option>
            </select>
            <select name="reportTime" style="width:100%">
                <option value="daily">Daily</option>
                <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
            </select>
            <a href="#" id="updateReport"><button>Update Chart</button></a> 
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

chart.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="/reportbuilder.do?reportType=${reportType}&reportScope=${reportScope}&reportTime=${reportTime}" alt="Image Loading Failed">
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you can process parameters on other JSP:

```
$("#chart1").load("/chart.jsp,     
                  {reportType:${reportType},
                   reportScope:${reportScope},
                   reportTime:{reportTime}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the placeholders you are using in javascript are empty. This javascript code is executed in the client side (browser), so they are not dynamically replaced by anything (that is what I think you are expecting), they are replaced by an empty value when the JSP is rendered:

```
$("#chart1").load("/chart.jsp?reportType=${reportType}&reportScope=${reportScope}&reportTime=${reportTime}");
```

Your should obtain their values from the html form. Give the selects an id and obtain their values using for example `$("#reportType")`